# Get available space on ALL devices on server

Tags: linux, shell, automation, ansible, scripting

```
  tasks:
    - name: Disk usage from device
      shell: df -h /dev/(device path) --output\=pcent | tail -1 && df -h /dev/(device path) --output\=pcent | tail -1
      register: devicespace
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ devicespace.stdout_lines }}"
```

Currently, I have to hardcode each device path on the server. This specific server I am testing on has two devices How can I alter this script so that it can pull the available space on all of the devices on the server. I'v tried /dev/* but that doesn't seem to work. The end goal is to pull available space on all the devices on the server and send an email if the available space is less that 10%.

Comment: so just `df -h`?

Comment: That returns everything. I am specifically trying to look at just the devices on the server. Like anything that has the path starting with /dev/

Comment: (a) I'm not sure Ansible is a great monitoring solution; there are probably better tools for that. (b) The `ansible_mounts` variable may have all the information you're looking for.

Comment: @larsks  I have tried several ansible scripts using the ansible_mounts but it seems the numbers are off and its looking at specific files or only the root device. I need to get the available space from all devices and the df -h is the only command that I have found thus far that gives me all that information. I just need to narrow it down to look specifically at the devices. Anything starting with /dev/

Comment: sooo like `df -h -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs`? `df -h | grep '^/dev/'` ? Really....

Comment: @KamilCuk 

`df -h | grep '^/dev/'` worked.. but then I only want to output percentage used. 

`df -h | grep '^/dev/' --output\=pcent` throws an error.

Comment: `--outpu` is an option to `df` not to `grep`. You may learn from https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide and https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . So get output from df, filter it, output only stuff you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df has --output to select the fields to be printed. This can then be further processed with grep and so:

```
tasks:
- name: Disk usage from device
  shell: df -h --output=source,pcent | grep '^/dev
  register: devicespace
- debug:
    msg: "{{ devicespace.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! 

So now I need to figure out how to set the condition that if devicespace > 90% send an email. 

Iv tried 
when: "{{ devicespace> "90%" }}"  and it throws an error. Any insight?

Comment: @Ali, for the requirement "if space >% send mail" you will find several answers here on SO already, in example [check diskspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077630/) or [print available disk space and send email notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963521/).